# Ordenar mês que está em extenso no Postgres

Tags: postgresql, order-by, classificação

Preciso fazer um `ORDER BY` em uma tabela `mes` que possui os meses em extenso e em português `(Janeiro, Fevereiro...)`. Ela não tem nenhuma relação com nenhuma outra coluna da tabela. É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Duvido que apenas pela string o consigas fazer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estive a investigar e penso que te encontrei uma solução, passando cada `string` do mês para o respetivo número (ex.: `Janeiro = 1`):

```
SELECT 
       CASE 
            WHEN mes = "Janeiro" THEN 1
            WHEN mes = "Fevereiro" THEN 2
            WHEN mes = "Março" THEN 3
            WHEN mes = "Abril" THEN 4
            ...
       END as meses
       , mes //apresentar também o mês em string ao lado do número
FROM tbl_meses;
ORDER BY meses ASC
```

Comment: Funcionou com o segundo código, só tive que mudar algumas coisas, coloquei LIKE invés de = e trocar as aspas duplas por simples. Obrigado.

Comment: Detectei agora um probleminha... o resultado do mês está vindo como integer, ao invés de vir como ele é originalmente.

Comment: Sim, foi necessário para o `order by`. Mas podes na mesma apresentar o mês, vou editar

Answer (score 2):

Se essa tabela é apenas para traduzir os meses uma solução simples é adicionar uma coluna com número do mês a ordenação deve ser feita pelo ano e por essa coluna nova.

Caso tenha um campo date ou similar e quer exibir o mês por extenso em português pode definir o locale na sessão e ordenar pelo mês.

```
set lc_time = 'portuguese';
select to_char(data,'tmmonth') from tabela order by extract(year from data), extract(month from data)
```

Comment: Depois vou editar a resposta para adicionar as configurações necessárias para o locale funcionar corretamente.